# How to count comments while selection posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

**tb_posts** `id,title,description`

**tb_comments** `id,post_id,comment`

I want to select all posts with count of comments.

How will write single query for it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do:

```
SELECT tb_posts.id, tb_posts.title, tb_posts.description 
    FROM  tb_posts INNER JOIN tb_comments
       ON  tb_posts.id = tb_comments.post_id
GROUP BY tb_posts.id, tb_posts.title, tb_posts.description 
HAVING COUNT(*) > SOME_THRESHOLD_VALUE
```

Comment: True, but it limits the results to those having a certain count which was that was the requirement. Adding `COUNT(tb_comments.id)` to the select statement includes the count.

Comment: ya... ok.. I think the OP is not that clear, "with comments" either means based on comments or the resultant table should have the count of comments.

Comment: In which case our combined efforts should be sufficient ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.id,a.title,a.description, count(b.id) FROM tb_posts a, tb_comments b, 
  WHERE a.id=b.post_id;
```

Comment: It is select rows if only tb_comments has post_id. If post has no comments then ??

Comment: If a post has no comments then the `count` value will be 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT tb_posts.title, COUNT(tb_comments.id)
FROM tb_comments LEFT JOIN tb_posts ON tb_posts.id = tb_comments.post_id
GROUP BY tb_comments.post_id, tb_posts.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution

```
   SELECT p.id,p.title,p.description,c.cm FROM tb_posts AS p LEFT JOIN    
     (SELECT post_id,count(id) as cm FROM `tb_comments` GROUP BY post_id) AS c
 ON p.id = c.post_id
```